# Unable to click on Siebel application upload button

Tags: c#, selenium, button, upload, siebel

I have visible and clickable Siebel application button below, but Selenium C# unable to click it.

```
<input type="file" tabindex="0" class="ruFileInput" multiple="multiple" name="AsyncUpload1file1" id="AsyncUpload1file0" size="23"/>
```

Here is my code:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=AsyncUpload1file0]")).Click();
```

Note that I have checked it's visible and clickable as well.
Anyone have same issue, please help?

Comment: You should add quotes around the id... see my answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around the id string `'`:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='AsyncUpload1file0']")).Click();
```

Hope this helps!